# R axis ticks not displaying on polar log plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, polar-coordinates

I'm making a logarithmic polar plot in Matplotlib, and for some reason after switching to "log=True" my raxis ticks disappeared. Here is my plotting code:

```
# <Matplotlib imports...>

ax = subplot(111, polar=True)
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_ylim(0,.04)
plt.scatter(dra, dphys, c="red", cmap=cm.hsv)
plt.scatter(wra, wphys, cmap=cm.hsv)
ax.set_xticklabels(['0','3','6','9','12','15','18','21'])
ax.set_yticklabels(['1','5','10','30','100','1000','10000'])

show()
```

As you can see by that final line, those are the ticks I'd like to show up on it. How can I make this work?

[image: Picture of plot]

Answer (score 1):

Set log scale after plot and use `xticks`.

```
from matplotlib.pylab import *

r = np.arange(0., 10000., .01)
phi = 5. * np.pi * r

ax = subplot(111, polar=True)
ax.plot(phi, r, color='r', linewidth=1.5)
ax.set_xticklabels(['0','3','6','9','12','15','18','21'])
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_yticks([1,5,10,30,100,1000,10000])
ax.set_rlabel_position(60)
show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This helped. Quick questions though: one, the `set_rlabel_position` line isn't working for me (`'PolarAxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'set_ylabel_position'`).  Also, is there a way to make the label bigger/bolder? I have a lot of points plotted, and it's very hard to read.